Basic Properties of the generated algebra by a set.
Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a semi-algebra over a nonempty set $X$ and let $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F} \subseteq P(X)$ and $F \subseteq X$.
I'm wondering if it is true that the following propeties holds:

$ (1) \ \mathscr{A}(\mathcal{F}\cap F) = \mathscr{A}(\mathcal{F}) \cap F$
$ (2) \ \mathcal{E} \subseteq \mathcal{F} \implies \mathscr{A}(\mathcal{E}) \subseteq \mathscr{A}(\mathcal{F})$
$ (3) \  \mathscr{A}(\mathcal{F}) = \bigcup_{\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}, card(\mathcal{G}) \leq \omega}\mathscr{A}(\mathcal{G})$
$ (4) \ \mathscr{A}(\sigma (\mathcal{F}))= \sigma (\mathcal{F})$
$ (5) \ \sigma(\mathscr{A}(\mathcal{F}))=\sigma (\mathcal{F})$
$(6) \ \mathcal{S} \cap F$ is a semi-algebra over $F$

Properties $(1),(2),(3)$ holds if we change $\mathscr{A}$ to $\sigma$. But I don't know if they keep being true. Anyway, could someone help me to verify each property?
I'm denoting here $\mathcal{G} \cap G = \{H \cap G : H \in \mathcal{G}\}$ and $\mathscr{A}(\mathcal{G})$ to be the generated algebra (over X) by $\mathcal{G}$, whenever $\mathcal{G}$ is a family of subsets of $X$ and $G$ a subset of $X$.
